# Error Message no visible @interface for UIToolbar declares the selector 'setItems:animated:'

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm building a UISplitviewController with this code:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    barButtonItem.title = @"Customers";
    NSMutableArray *items = [[self.toolbar items] mutableCopy];
    [items insert0bject:barButtonItem atlndex:0]:
    [self.toolbar setItems:items animatd:YES];

    masterPopoverController = pc;
}

- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController *)svc
     willShowViewController: (UIViewController *)aViewController
  invalidatingBarButtonItem: (UIBarButtonItem *)button
{
    NSMutableArray *items = [[self.toolbar items] mutableCopy];
    [items removeObject:button];
    [self.toolbar setItems:items animatied:YES];
    masterPopoverController = nil;
}
```

I'm getting the same error on two different lines: on the line

```
masterPopoverController = pc;
```

and

```
[self.toolbar setItems:items animatied:YES];
```

Xcode shows me the error

> No visible @interface for 'UIToolbar' declares the selector 'setItems:animatd' *(or 'setItems:animatied' in the second)*

How do I correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the current code with:

```
[self.toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

you simply spelled "`animated`" wrong in those two lines of code.

fix it, and they will compile.